# Unable to deploy next js app on AWS Elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am trying to deploy Next.js app on AWS elastic beanstalk but encountering below errors:
[image]

Thanks in advance.